# Password security in a Snapchat photo

Tags: passwords

This is going to be an extremely stupid question, so forgive my ignorance.

Let's say I took a Snapchat photo of one of my passwords written in plaintext (let's ignore for a moment the security vulnerability that comes with even having a password in plaintext). I use the colored pen feature in Snapchat to "cross out" my password so it is no longer visible.

I then send this Snapchat to my friend Eve and she does two things:

- Takes a screenshot of the picture I sent her
- Hacks into Snapchat's database and gets the actual image file that I sent her

Is she able to "erase" the colored pen to reveal my plaintext password? If so, is she able to do with either of the bulleted pictures, or just the second one?

Comment: Side note: Aren't you concerned what snapchat employees could do?

Answer (score 2):

No, she cannot remove the colored pen if she just takes a screenshot.

How Snapchat stores photos is a question for Snapchat themselves. Although they will most likely deny that they save them ([they do](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/snapchat-ftc-settlement,news-18754.html)), it all depends if they store the photos in layers or an all together, un-editable screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

No, neither her nor Snapchat will have the original image.

This is because the pen and other image modifications performed are done client side. So the snap transmitted only contains the version with the password scribbled out. This is in the image and cannot be reversed without the original which your Snapchat app *should* discard. (Should - but historically people have been able to locate the originals on their own phone.)

Comment: Are you **sure** about that? Might as well transmit original image + modifications as vectors to server, which merges them and sends a flat image to the clients. Theoretically it's possible.

Comment: It's possible but it isn't the case. Nor would it be good to spend bandwidth and processing power on something you can do clientside.

Comment: No it would not make sense to do it server-side, I agree with you. But I at least do not know how snapchat is actually implemented and can therefore not give security advice in this particular regard. That's why I ask, do you know what you state for **sure**? Or is it an educated guess?

Comment: As mentioned in my answer users have been able to navigate their phone and find "snaps". The snaps that were sent where post edited images.